# How to get the result using awk

Tags: awk

++++++++++
INPUT:

```
EMPNO 16:    (DEP,GROUP) DEPTNO:10, GROUP:36 , AREA-CA    LOGIN TIM: loginday=10 min 30 sec loginrec=1 min 30 sec 1: working for 'advanced automation'
EMPNO 17:    (DEP,GROUP) DEPTNO:4, GROUP:1010 , AREA-CA    LOGIN TIM: loginday=9 min 30 sec loginrec=2 sec  2: working for 'vacation'
```

OUTPUT needed:

```
EMP       DEPT                   LOGIN REC                  WORKING FOR
===       ====                   =========                  ===========
EMPNO 16: DEPTNO:10, GROUP:36    1 min 30 sec 1             advanced automation
EMPNO 17: DEPTNO:4,  GROUP:1010  2 sec                      vacation
```

++++++++++

How to get the output  using only awk in a single command line .

Basically as you can see there are few rules that i want to apply on the input ( which i got through applying awk in a big file that i am processing):

1. Get the  empno from the first field
2. Get the DEPTNO, GROUP from the second field
3. get the loginrec from the third field.
4. get the string inside one field.
5. Everything should be indented in single ( especially when data is varying in say 3rd field, when sometimes times are only in seconds and sometimes in minutes. Or the deptno and group number variation.

I have got this input by processing a big file and below was the previous step:

```
EMPNO 16:
    (DEP,GROUP) DEPTNO:10, GROUP:36 , AREA-CA
     LOGIN TIM: loginday=10 min 30 sec loginrec=1 min 30 sec
        working for 'advanced automation'
```

Comment: Are those tab separated fields?

Comment: Not exactly , see my last edit. I have got the input by concatenating the previous step. In that step there were spaces before the text for few of the lines and that is what got propagated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    print "EMP", "DEPT", "LOGIN REC", "WORKING FOR"
    print "===", "====", "=========", "==========="
}
{
    match($0,/loginrec=/)
    loginRec = workingFor = substr($0,RSTART+9)
    sub(/:.*/,"",loginRec)
    gsub(/^[^\047]*\047|\047[^\047]*$/,"",workingFor)
    print $1" "$2, $4" "$5, loginRec, workingFor
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
EMP     DEPT    LOGIN REC       WORKING FOR
===     ====    =========       ===========
EMPNO 16:       DEPTNO:10, GROUP:36     1 min 30 sec 1  advanced automation
EMPNO 17:       DEPTNO:4, GROUP:1010    2 sec  2        vacation

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
EMP        DEPT                  LOGIN REC       WORKING FOR
===        ====                  =========       ===========
EMPNO 16:  DEPTNO:10, GROUP:36   1 min 30 sec 1  advanced automation
EMPNO 17:  DEPTNO:4, GROUP:1010  2 sec  2        vacation
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.(completely based on your shown samples and is not taking care of proper spaces as per shown by OP in expected output)

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print "EMP       DEPT                   LOGIN REC                  WORKING FOR"
}
match($0,/^EMPNO [0-9]+:/){
  EMP=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/DEPTNO:[0-9]+\, GROUP:[0-9]+/){
  DEPT=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/loginrec.*sec/){
  LOGIN=substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)
}
match($0,/working for \047.*/){
  WORKING=substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-14)
}
{
  print EMP,DEPT,LOGIN,WORKING
  EMP=DEPT=LOGIN=WORKING=""
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: it works, how to get the indentation/formatting also  in it?